# Check the existing id, update or insert values from the CheckBox

Tags: c#, dapper, identity

I have a small problem with updating an existing ID, I do not know exactly how to refer it to `C#` using `DAPPER`.

My idea is that the value from the checkbox `1 = true, 0 = false` for a specific month, I enter the database, currently I always do ELSE block, how do I set up to update the ID?

This is my code:

```
private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int _value;
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        _value = checkBox1.ImageIndex = 1;
    else
        _value =  checkBox1.ImageIndex = 0;
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Zeiterfassung"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string insertQuery = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[MONATSSALDO] WHERE [ID]=@ID) //how to refer this id?
                            UPDATE [dbo].[MONATSSALDO] SET [MA_ID]=@MA_ID, [MONATSSALDO]=@MONATSSALDO, [DATUM]=@DATUM, [MONAT_IST_KONTROLLIERT]=@MONAT_IST_KONTROLLIERT WHERE [ID]=@ID
                            ELSE
                            INSERT INTO [dbo].[MONATSSALDO]([ID],[MA_ID], [MONATSSALDO], [DATUM], [MONAT_IST_KONTROLLIERT])
                            VALUES (@ID, @MA_ID, @MONATSSALDO, @DATUM, @MONAT_IST_KONTROLLIERT)";
        var result = db.Execute(insertQuery, new { MA_ID=userID,  MONATSSALDO= 4, DATUM = calendar1.CurrentDate, MONAT_IST_KONTROLLIERT = _value });
    }
}
```

this looks like my scheme at the base

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MONATSSALDO](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MA_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MONATSSALDO] [float] NOT NULL,
    [DATUM] [date] NULL,
    [MONAT_IST_KONTROLLIERT] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [MONATSSALDO_ID] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MONATSSALDO] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MONATSSALDO]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MONATSSALDO]
GO
```

The ID is Identity, and it always increases for 1. Is it at all possible?

Comment: See: [Adding Parameters to Commands](https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes he's using Dapper.

Comment: I can not find an example with dapper for entering parameters.

Comment: Is `SqlConnection` dapper?

Comment: There is a not pretty solution which would be to construct the string with the id and then execute it with the parameters

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes it's a fantastic utility, that extends on IDbConnection, essentially a Micro-ORM.  The parameters are set up automatically.

Comment: Should I change the code then?

Comment: Here I found a tutorial: [Dapper / Parameter](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper#parameter).

Comment: @lasta also note the authors use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in the `Dapper.Contrib` project https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Contrib/SqlMapperExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the ID as parameter

```
val = "value";
cnn.Execute("insert into Table(val) values (@val)", new {val});

cnn.Execute("update Table set val = @val where Id = @id", new {val, id = 1});
```

**Edit**

First you have to select the object that you want to update id exist, you need to know which one it is.. only then you can perform an update to that object..

So then just pass that Id as a parameter..

Try to add a property ID to checkBox1 object and set that property to the value of the specific month. So when you get to this method CheckBox1_CheckedChanged you grab the value of ID and pass it as parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use the answer, please read my post, I want the existing id to update the value. Your answer is not helpful.

Comment: @lasta, if you want to update a specific row you need the ID,  you can't guess, you need to do a relation between checkBox and month and when you get to this method you need to use that ID to update that row

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store the ID with each checkbox and link the same event handler to each checkbox, such as the Tag field of the checkbox.

```
        checkBox1.Tag = 1;
        checkBox1.CheckedChanged += HandleCheckBox;

        checkBox2.Tag = 2;
        checkBox2.CheckedChanged += HandleCheckBox;
```

Then in your event handler:

```
 int id = (int)(sender as CheckBox).Tag;
        ...
```